# Outlook removes email adresses on mailto: links

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I open a **mailto:** link on a web page, my default email client, Outlook 2010 is launched.

My problem is that when outlook "resolves" the email address and changes them from this:
[image]

to this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

It removes some of the emails as can be seen from the pictures. By clicking manually on the To... or Cc... fields I am able to control from what field an email will be removed. If I don't click on anything and just wait, the email will be removed from the To... field.

I have tested that this problem occurs whether the email address are present or not in my Address Book.

It is always reproducible. I have been able to reproduce it with the following html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <a href="mailto:test1@test.abc?subject=Test&cc=test2@test.abc;test3@test.abc">Test MailTo</a>
</html>
```

And with actual mailto links.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: Copying that exact HTML I was not able to reproduce this. Outlook 2010 & 
Google Chrome 55.0.2883.87 (Official Build) m (32-bit)